# Every ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt d]$ is finitely generated by at most two elements of the form $a, b + c \sqrt d$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I'm trying to show that every nonzero ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt d]$ is finitely generated and I'm trying to achieve that by showing that
if $d$ is squarefree and $d \neq -1$ then is it true that for every nonzero non-principal ideal $I$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt d]$, there exists $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $I = (a, b\sqrt d)$. I think this is true but this post [Prove that every nonzero prime ideal is maximal in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607324) says that the generators actually are $a, b + c \sqrt(d)$ so i dont know why or which part of the statement of the beginning is wrong. And if it is wrong, how could I go about proving that the ideals are finitely generated.

Comment: If $d=2,$ $I=\langle 3+\sqrt 2\rangle$ has $7$ and $7\sqrt2,$ but those two don’t generate all of $I.$ Show there is no $a,b.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews What if $I$ is not principal ? I'm actually trying to show that every ideal $I \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt(d)]$ is finitely generated

Comment: Your title asks something a lot different than your first sentence. Can you please clarify what you want, actually?

Comment: @rschwieb I'm trying to show that every ideal in $Z[\sqrt(d)]$ is finitely generated and I'm trying to do that by showing they are either principal or generated by two elements which I believe are the two elements in the post

Comment: @endeavor I think you should change your title from "is finitely generated" to "is generated by these two elements," then.  Otherwise one should solve the problem by noting that the ring is a quotient of $\mathbb Z[x]$ which is noetherian, and so are all its quotients.  Otherwise you have two questions which appear to have two different answers.

Comment: It’s not true for non-principal ideals, either. Literally, pick some non-principal ideal usually known.

Comment: Change noted: thank you.

Comment: E.g., $d=-5,$ $I=\langle 2,1+\sqrt{-5}\rangle.$

Comment: I see that now, thank you very much. What about the post that I linked ? Are the generators there correct ?

Comment: What do you know about subgroups of finitely generated free abelian groups? That is, $\Bbb{Z}$-modules?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Unfortunately I did not get to study free groups or modules so nothing\

Comment: @endeavor It might be too early for you to talk about $\Bbb Z[\sqrt d]$. You at least need to have some knowledge about finitely generated abelian groups.

Comment: @WhatsUp This is one of the question posed in my algebraic number theory course so i dont think that this is too early

Comment: That's too bad, because then you would immediately know that any non-zero ideal of $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt d]$ is also a free abelian group of rank two. In other words, it can be generated by two elements *as an abelian group*. The result about it being finitely generated as an ideal follows immediately.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Is there any other way of showing this without going into free group, etc ?

Comment: @rschwieb I did learn about Noetherian ring but only surface level knowledge so I did not know about its quotients

Comment: @endeavor I mean it seems that you are not well prepared for taking a course in algebraic number theory. You might need a more basic course such as abstract algebra. Free abelian groups are so basic that you definitely need to know them to proceed to more advanced topics. Also you seem to be confusing "free abelian groups" with "free groups", so I'm really not sure whether you have the prerequest knowledge.

Comment: @WhatsUp the post that I linked shows another method that does not use free abelian group so is that method correct or not because I did not see any indications that it is wrong in said post's comments

Comment: @WhatsUp The course i'm taking  at my uni is mainly number theory and a bit of algebraic number theory. I did take abstract algebra but i'm certain that free abelian group was never taught

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every non-zero ideal $I\lhd\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ must have non-zero intersection with $\mathbb{Z}$ (that is easy to see) so $I\cap\mathbb{Z}$ is a non-zero ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ and therefore principal so choose a generator $a>0$. If $I=(a)\lhd\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ we are done, so assume that $(a)\subsetneq I$. Then there are elements of form $x+y\sqrt{d}\in I\setminus(a)$ and we can take integer combinations of these with multiples of $a$ to get $b+c\sqrt{d}\in I\setminus(a)$ where either $b=0$ or $b>0$ is minimal. A straightforward argument now shows that every element of $I$ is in $(a,b+c\sqrt{d})$.

A similar argument works to show the result for the ring of integers in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$ when $d\equiv1\bmod{4}$, this is the set of numbers of form $a+b\dfrac{(-1+\sqrt{d})}{2}$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$. For other $d$, the ring of integers is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$.

Comment: did you intend to write 'to get $b+c\sqrt{d}$' instead of 'to get $b+b\sqrt{d}$' ?

Comment: Yes - thanks, I have corrected that.