# Terminology: Subrings with the property that an element is invertible iff it is invertible in the larger ring.

Tags: ring-theory, terminology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a term for an “inverse-closed” subring of a ring?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57629/is-there-a-term-for-an-inverse-closed-subring-of-a-ring)

This is a question about terminology.
Is there a standard name for a subring $A \subset B$ that has the property that an element $a \in A$ is invertible in $A$ if and only if $a$ is invertible as an element of $B$?
If $a$ is invertible in $A$ then it is evidently invertible in $B$, so another way of stating the desired property is that $A$ is a subring such that if $a\in A$ is invertible in $B$ then its inverse $a^{-1}$ is contained in $A$.

For example, the center of a ring always has this property.