# "$S$ is the unique irreducible $\operatorname{End}(S)$-module"

Tags: abstract-algebra, simple-groups

Let $S$ be a finite-dimensional vector space. Then $S$ is an irreducible $\operatorname{End}(S)$-module. Furthermore I was told that $S$ is the only irreducible $\operatorname{End}(S)$-module. I guess that this means that if $E$ is an irreducible $\operatorname{End}(S)$-module, then there is a unique isomorphism of modules, i.e. $\operatorname{Hom_{\operatorname{End}(S)}}(S,E)$ contains a unique invertible element. Since I have no prior training in algebra, I am hoping that someone can either name a reference or outline the proof.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple $M_n(D)$-module with $D$ a division ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/874233/simple-m-nd-module-with-d-a-division-ring) $\text{End}(S)$ is just the matrix algebra.

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist I don't see why that answers my question, could you elaborate please?

Comment: Simple = irreducible, and instead of $D$ you have just a field $k$. $S$ is simple since e.g. $GL_n(k) \subset M_n(k) = R$ acts transitively on $S \setminus \{0\}$. If $S = Rs$, then $\varphi: _RR \to S$, $r \mapsto rs$, is an onto left $R$-module homomorphism; by the first isomorphism theorem $S \cong _RR/\ker \varphi$, but $R$ is semisimple, so $S$ is actually isomorphic to a **sub**module of $_RR$ = (minimal) left ideal. Then use any of the answers, say the third if you like it. In the interpretation you gave the "uniqueness" does not hold, i.e. an isomorphism should merely exist.

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist Thank you for the comment! Concerning the uniqueness: I think that if $T:S\to E$ does the job, then $\lambda T$ with $\lambda\neq 0$ also does the job, so indeed no uniqueness - but almost: I think that if $T_1$ and $T_2$ are both Clifford isomorphisms from $S$ to $E$, then there is $\lambda\neq 0$ with $T_2=\lambda T_1$.

Comment: What's a *Clifford* isomorphism in this context? What you wrote is indeed correct, it's [Schur's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_lemma#Formulation_in_the_language_of_modules).

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist Sorry for the confusion, I am considering the Clifford algebra $\operatorname{Cl}(V)$ of an even-dimensional Euclidean vector space $V$ and the complexification of $\operatorname{Cl}(V)$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{End}(S)$ for some complex vector space $S$. So I just meant that $T_1,T_2\in\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{End}(S)}(S,E)$ are invertible. Unfortunately I don't see why what I just said follows from Schur's lemma, could you elaborate please? Note that $\lambda$ was meant to be a scalar/a complex number.

Comment: For any pair of isomorphisms $T_1$ and $T_2$, $T_2^{-1} T_1$ is an automorphism of $S$. In the link they prove the endomorphism ring to be a skew field, and later in the section they comment that if the base field is algebraically closed, then the skew field in question is equal to the base field. (See e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/405217).)

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist Thank you, but I think that there is a more elementary way which doesn't require the field to be algebraically closed: I used [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/27808/572841).

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow: why do they *a priori* have to commute?

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist Suppose that $T_1,T_2\in\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{End}(S)}(S,E)$ are invertible and let $c$ be the action of $S$ on $E$. Then$$\forall A\in\operatorname{End}(S):c(A)=T_i\circ A\circ T^{-1}_i$$for $i=1,2$ and hence$$\forall A:T^{-1}_1T_2A=AT^{-1}_1T_2$$

Comment: So $T_1^{-1}T_2=\lambda 1$ and hence $T_2= \lambda T_1$.

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist Sorry, the first comment should say "action of $\operatorname{End}(S)$ on $E$".