# Is $1/2$ in $\mathbb{Z}[2^{1/2},2^{1/3},2^{1/4},...]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I was wondering if $\frac{1}{2}$ is in the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[2^{1/2},2^{1/3},2^{1/4},...]$. I don't think it is, and I've been trying to prove by contradiction. So far I've shown that if this is true, then $R=\mathbb{Z}[...,2^{-1/3},2^{-1/2},2^{1/2},2^{1/3},...]$, which seems unusual. Do I need more techniques from field theory to make headway? Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: You can search for an ideal $I$ containing $2$ such that the quotient $R/I$ is obviously not the zero ring.

Comment: $1/2$ is not integral.

Comment: Is it clear what essentially distinguishes between this problem and the problem of whether $1/2$ is in $\mathbb Z[2^{1/2},2^{1/3},\dots,2^{1/10}]$?

Comment: @AlexOrtiz a solution to the problem you stated would probably be easily adapted to solve my problem.

Comment: Every number in your ring is an algebraic integer, i.e. a root of a monic poly with integer coef's, but $1/2$ is not (by the Rational Root Test).  Generally integral extensions can't  change a nonunit to a unit (similarly for ideals, i.e. nonunit ideals survive, e.g. see the paper cited [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/57702/242) for various characterizations of integral extensions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going off of Kenta's and Bill Dubuque's comments, we note that $\mathbb{Z}[2^{1/2},2^{1/3},...]$ is an integral extension of $\mathbb{Z}$, since every root of $2$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$. If $1/2\in \mathbb{Z}[2^{1/2},2^{1/3},...]$, then $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ must be an extension of $\mathbb{Z}$ contained in $\mathbb{Z}[2^{1/2},2^{1/3},...]$, and thus an integral extension. However, $1/2$ is not integral over $\mathbb{Z}$, and we arrive at a contradiction.